# Socket.io - TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'transport')

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, websocket, socket.io

**Issue:**
Local development in VS Code runs without problems or crashes.
However, when I upload the application to a server (node.js), it runs until a Socket.io connection is established or the connected web page is refreshed.
I don't know if this relates to the admin UI specifically as in the filepath below or if this is a Socket.io issue in general.
Perhaps this also has to do with the middleware which holds up a request until an action has completed so that non-existent data cannot be accessed.

I already tried to update the npm package, but nothing has changed.

```js
// middleware is executed on every request
var Map = require('./file')

module.exports = (io, socket) => {
    socket.use(async (packet, next) => {
        var key = socket.handshake.auth.key
        var data = Map.get(key)   
    
        while(!data.action) {   // true for finished or false for loading
            await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve,10))
        }

        socket.data = data
        next()
    })
}
```

**Serverconsole:**

```
/usr/src/app/node_modules/@socket.io/admin-ui/dist/index.js:233
socket.data._admin.transport = transport.name;
^

TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'transport')
at Socket.<anonymous> (/usr/src/app/node_modules/@socket.io/admin-ui/dist/index.js:233:42)
at Socket.emit (node:events:390:28)
at WebSocket.onPacket (/usr/src/app/node_modules/engine.io/build/socket.js:214:22)
at WebSocket.emit (node:events:390:28)
at WebSocket.onPacket (/usr/src/app/node_modules/engine.io/build/transport.js:92:14)
at WebSocket.onData (/usr/src/app/node_modules/engine.io/build/transport.js:101:14)
at WebSocket.<anonymous> (/usr/src/app/node_modules/engine.io/build/transports/websocket.js:20:19)
at WebSocket.emit (node:events:390:28)
at Receiver.receiverOnMessage (/usr/src/app/node_modules/ws/lib/websocket.js:1022:20)
at Receiver.emit (node:events:390:28)

Node.js v17.3.1
```

Comment: Your `while` loop  `while(!action) { await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve,10))}` will not work if `action` starts out false` because nothing in the loop ever changes its value.  So, if `action` starts out false, this loop will just go forever.  If you truly want to poll the `action` value and wait for it to change (generally a bad way to write code), then you have to get the newest version of `action` INSIDE the loop.

Comment: FYI, the error you're getting appears to be telling you that `socket.data._admin` is `undefined`.  So, you have to back up in your code to figure out why that is.  You don't show any code that builds the `data` object so we have no idea what is or isn't in that object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also asked the developers the question on GitHub directly and I received an answer.

I was told that data is overwritten by using `socket.data = value`.
If I change it to `socket.socketDate` for example, then it works fine.

See the full answer on GitHub with the refered code of the socket.io admin ui:
[github socket.io-admin-ui issue-55](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-admin-ui/issues/55#issuecomment-1269391896)